# Mac OS 14.0 - Safari simulators not visible

Tags: safari, xcode-simulator, sonoma

I am trying to use developer tools in Sonoma and the simulators aren't working.

Xcode is installed and I have installed the simulators. I can't access any of them even the default ones that should be pre-installed.

1. I am using Safari: Version 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1)
2. I am examining a webpage using the developer tools.
3. I am viweing the page in responsive design mode.
4. When I go to view the page in a simulator I
   have no options.

Restarts and re-installs don't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to launch the simulator first.

1. Open Simulators app (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator).
2. File → Open Simulator and choose a device.

   [image]
3. Back in macOS's Safari, choose the running simulator device from the Responsive Design Mode.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you. So damn obvious.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't obvious *at all*, and isn't mentioned anywhere on Apple's support page! Bad Apple. Bad.

Comment: when i click on a simulator from the drop down in safari, safari just crashes.